# What could be causing Code Contracts to cancel a build operation?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, code-contracts

I'm encountering a very strange issue when trying to build a solution that uses Code Contracts. For no appearant reason, at some point build gets canceled - or so it says in VS's output window. There are no compilation error of any sort and if I choose a different build configuration - one that is NOT using Code Contracts - the solution builds without any issues.

Is there anything that would make Code Contracts cancel a build?

I'm using [visual-studio-2013](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2013) with Update 4 and CC version 1.7.11106.10, which is to this date the latest.

Comment: In the Output pane, change the "Show output from" dropdown to "Code Contracts Editor Extensions" and see if there are additional messages. Also, check the Warnings and Messages in the Error List pane.

Comment: @Keith I'm afraid I don't have Editor Extensions. I'm using VS2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I seem to have found the problem.

Apparently, Code Contracts will cause building to fail upon stuff like placing call to Require method after Ensure method, calling Require with nested calls to methods not marked with Pure, etc. These are shown as warnings within the build output, NOT as errors in the error window.

Simply review the warnings, try fixing them and rebuild.